# Нужна помощь в верстке

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть строка текста, которая переносится и в ней собственно находится кнопка, которая что-то делает. Как правильно сверстать подобную структуру?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задать обтекание float: left

Comment: Попробовал добавить, но не вышло. Можете пожалуйста, показать как это нужно сделать?

Comment: @mik.ov, зачем бы это?

Answer (score 3):

```html
Вообще-то оно по умолчанию именно так и работает.
Вообще-то оно по умолчанию именно так и работает.
Вообще-то оно по умолчанию именно так и работает.
Вообще-то оно по умолчанию именно так и работает.
Вот: <button>Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  max-width: 300px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  текс текст текст текст <a href="https://css-tricks.com/" class="button">Тык</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем было кнопку div'ом делать?

Comment: @Qwertiy поменял